# Using glyphicon-triangle-left with Intel XDK it shows up as a Chinese character

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intel-xdk

I am building a multi OS app with Intel XDK. I use a Sony Xperia Z1 Compact to debug. It seems to support boostrap [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons), this one works;

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

But when I use this one;

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

It shows up (kinda) like this: 繢 (it looks a lot like this, but my scetching skills are not quite up to the task)

Anyone got a clue what is happening here?

*Edit, found out what else is no longer working, and I think it is in the Device with auto translate or something like it...

The List:

glyphicon glyphicon-cd

glyphicon glyphicon-save-file

glyphicon glyphicon-open-file

glyphicon glyphicon-level-up

glyphicon glyphicon-copy

glyphicon glyphicon-paste

glyphicon glyphicon-alert

glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer

glyphicon glyphicon-king

glyphicon glyphicon-queen

glyphicon glyphicon-pawn

glyphicon glyphicon-bishop

glyphicon glyphicon-knight

glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula

glyphicon glyphicon-tent

glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard

glyphicon glyphicon-bed

glyphicon glyphicon-apple

glyphicon glyphicon-erase

glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass

glyphicon glyphicon-lamp

glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate

glyphicon glyphicon-piggy-bank

glyphicon glyphicon-scissors

glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin

glyphicon glyphicon-btc

glyphicon glyphicon-xbt

glyphicon glyphicon-yen

glyphicon glyphicon-jpy

glyphicon glyphicon-ruble

glyphicon glyphicon-rub

glyphicon glyphicon-scale

glyphicon glyphicon-ice-lolly

glyphicon glyphicon-ice-lolly-tasted

glyphicon glyphicon-education

glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal

glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical

glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger

glyphicon glyphicon-modal-window

glyphicon glyphicon-oil

glyphicon glyphicon-grain

glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses

glyphicon glyphicon-text-size

glyphicon glyphicon-text-color

glyphicon glyphicon-text-background

glyphicon glyphicon-object-align-top

glyphicon glyphicon-object-align-bottom

glyphicon glyphicon-object-align-horizontal

glyphicon glyphicon-object-align-left

glyphicon glyphicon-object-align-vertical

glyphicon glyphicon-object-align-right

glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right

glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left

glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom

glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top

glyphicon glyphicon-console

glyphicon glyphicon-superscript

glyphicon glyphicon-subscript

glyphicon glyphicon-menu-leftglyphicon glyphicon-menu-left

glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right

glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down

glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half a year and a upvote later, I have this working, just don't remember what exactly I did to make it so. But looking into my code these are the things that matter to make it work:

index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
```

and make sure you have the fonts in a folder like this:

```
www - index.html
    - fonts
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        - glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```